# Pass Multiple Value to a For Each in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone let me know if its possible to pass a parameter and an activity to a For Each in Azure Data Factory.

From the image I want to pass the parmater 'relativeURLs' into a For Each.

[image]

[image]

I would then like to do a For Each on the Lookup activity 'CompanyId Lookup
Is that possible?

Comment: Parameters and variables are global in Data Factory. You can't "pass" them to the Foreach activity, but they are accessible inside.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very confident if I get the ask correctly .

> I would then like to do a For Each on the Lookup activity 'CompanyId
> Lookup Is that possible?

This should go in the Foreach

> @activity('your lookup activity name ').output.value

Since the relative url is a parameter , you can reference that  inside the FE loop

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, can you let me know how to reference the relative url inside the FE loop?

Comment: Hi, can someone let me know how to enter a parameter in the Lookup activity as described by @Nagasi.?

Comment: Hi, SO members, can someone just let me know if @Nagasi solution is actually achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure to Pass Multiple Value to a For Each in Azure Data Factory.

create Linked service and dataset.
[image]
[image]
Create parameter of `relativeURL`  with respective values
[image]
Read the data by the Lookup activity.
[image]

```
@range(0,length(pipeline().parameters.relativeURL))
```

using two values inside Foreach using their indexes.
In ForEach, **check the Sequential**
[image]

Create variables for different values.
The value of the set variable from the lookup activity.

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].data[item()])
```

[image]
Value for this set variable from the pipeline parameters of the relativeURL

```
@pipeline().parameters.relativeURL[item()]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nagasai, thanks for reaching out. I testing your solution. If I select "**File path in dataset**" in "**Settings**" in the Lookup activity, I don't get a box to enter ```@range(0,length(pipeline().parameters.relativeURL))```. Should I select  **List of files** instead of File path in dataset ?

Comment: Hi @Patterson, It should be use in For each activity items bar.

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks @Nagasai. For some reason I thought you were suggesting it was to be used in Lookup activity. I will continue checking it out. Thank yoiu

Comment: Hi Nagasai, 
I'm getting the following error with your variable```{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'string(activity('MyLookup').output.value[0].companyId[item()])' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Set variable1",
    "details": ""
}```

Comment: Are you variables configued for ARRAYs, or STRINGs?